# SQL CREATE statement troubleshooting

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I'm using WAMPServer to make a database on localhost. I've changed the language settings to english but I keep getting errors in French. For example, submitting this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE table A
(
  A TIMESTAMP(1) PRIMARY,
  B TIMESTAMP(1),
  C VARCHAR(100),
  D VARCHAR(25)
)
```

results in this error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'A
(
  A TIMESTAMP(1),
  B TIMESTAMP(1),
  C ' Ã  la ligne 1
```

Can somebody help me out please?

Thanks

Comment: What should `TIMESTAMP(1)` be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set this in your session before entering the sql command?

```
SET lc_messages = 'en_US';
```

If you exit the session, then the settings revert to what [the database daemon has in its configuration files.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html).  You may have a setting or a shell script alias in your environment that has the error message variable set to French.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I found the answer in another post.

I needed to use the ` ` markers around 'Table A' (for anyone else interested the ` ` is left of the '1' button on the keyboard).

Also, thanks Greg for the tip about error messages.

Comment: The backtick is not on the "left of the `1` key on my keyboard ;) In general it is a bad idea to use table (or column) names that require quoting. Use a name without special characters and you'll have much less trouble in the long run.